# Basic example of AMI connection to Asterisk from Python script w/Starpy

Tags: python, asterisk

I have some years of solid experience working with asterisk but am new to python.
I want to connect from a python script and receive some events. I have created a manager user with `AMIUSERNAME` and `AMIPASSWORD` as credentials and tested working OK. I have also installed [StarPy](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/starpy/).
Then I run with the command `python ami.py USERNAME PASSWORD` the following script:

```
import sys
from starpy import manager
f = manager.AMIFactory(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
df = f.login('127.0.0.1',5038)
```

While monitoring the asterisk console and nothing happens. 
Does anyone know what I am missing?

I would like to send a Ping action and wait for a Pong response.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `f.login()` returns you an [`AMIProtocol`](http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/starpy/pydoc/starpy.manager.html#AMIProtocol) instance that has a `ping()` method.

I don't know anything about starpy, so some vague advice:

- Start Python as an interactive shell. Execute code and examine results on the spot. `help` function is your friend; try `help(df)` after the last line of your script.
- Look at the `examples` directory in starpy distribution. Maybe 90% of the code you need is already there.

Answer (score 0):

The following is pulled from the ami module (and a few other places) in the [Asterisk Test Suite](http://svn.asterisk.org/svn/testsuite/asterisk/trunk/).  We use starpy extensively throughout the Test Suite, so you may want to check it out for some examples.  Assume that the following code resides in some class with member method login.

```
def login(self):

  def on_login_success(self, ami):
      self.ami_factory.ping().addCallback(ping_response)
      return ami

  def on_login_error(self, reason):
      print "Failed to log into AMI"
      return reason

  def ping_response(self, ami)
      print "Got a ping response!"
      return ami

  self.ami_factory = manager.AMIFactory("user", "mysecret")
  self.ami_factory.login("127.0.0.1", 5038).addCallbacks(on_login_success, on_login_error)
```

Make sure as well that your manager.conf is configured properly.  For the Asterisk Test Suite, we use the following:

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038
bindaddr = 127.0.0.1

[user]
secret = mysecret
read = system,call,log,verbose,agent,user,config,dtmf,reporting,cdr,dialplan,test
write = system,call,agent,user,config,command,reporting,originate
```